# Proguard- Necessary to customize proguard-project.txt in order to obfuscate Source code?

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

I am trying to use `proguard` in order to obfuscate the source code of a very simple "Hello World" application, I am using `Eclipse` IDE.

The 2 steps I have taken so far are as follows:

```
1. Removed comment in project.properties file to enable Proguard

2. Right clicked on project>Android tools>Export unsigned Application Project
```

I then used [apktool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) to view the source code from the extracted APK.

What I noticed is that Proguard is not obfuscating the source code in the App. it is only obfuscating the `ActionBarActivity` super class and `XML Layout` names. Shown Below:

```
 package com.example.proguardtesttt;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.a.f;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;

    public class MainActivity extends f
    {
      protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle)
      {
        super.onCreate(paramBundle);
        setContentView(2130903064);
      }

      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu paramMenu)
      {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(2131492864, paramMenu);
        return true;
      }

      public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem paramMenuItem)
      {
        if (paramMenuItem.getItemId() == 2131034172)
          return true;
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(paramMenuItem);
      }
    }
```

Why is this happening? And how can I ensure to obfuscate all my source code also?

Note: I am almost certain that Proguard is enabled as the .apk is 300kb less than an identical .apk that does not have proguard enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some class names and method names can't be obfuscated, since that would break the application.

Your decompiler is making up the parameter names; they are not in the compiled code (and probably different from the original source code).